# How do I set the text() of a parent of a parent of an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, parent

I'm building a custom pulldown menu in jQuery.
Now I'd like to set the text of the A.select element to the text of the element that is clicked. But I can't get it to work.

This is the html:

```
<div class="pulldown">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="select">All cats/subs</a>
    <div class="options">
     <a href="javascript:;">Option one A</a>
     <a href="javascript:;">Option two A</a>
     <a href="javascript:;">Option three A</a>
        <a href="javascript:;">Option four A</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.pulldown').toggle(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index','110');
    $('.options', this).css('z-index','100').show('fast');
    $('.options A', this).click(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        $(this).closest('DIV.pulldown A.select').text(value);
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).css('z-index','10');
    $('.options', this).css('z-index','0').hide('fast');
}); });
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the toggle() function doing there?  It seems to me that after every toggle(), you're setting a new click() handler.  That doesn't look right.  Have you dumped to console.log() the contents of $(this).text(), to make sure you're actually finding the right thing?  It seems to me that you have to answer those two issues before you can start to diagnose the problem further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to work with if you clean up your HTML a little bit:

```
<dl class="menu">
    <dt class="topItem">All cats/subs</dt>
    <dd class="subItem">Option one A</dd>
    <dd class="subItem">Option two A</dd>
    <dd class="subItem">Option three A</dd>
</dl>
```

Then your jQuery boils down to this:

```
$(function() {
    var $topItem = $('.topItem');
    var $subItems = $('.subItem');

    $topItem.bind('click', function() {
        $subItems.toggle();
    });

    $subItems.bind('click', function() {
        $topItem.text($(this).text());
        $subItems.toggle();
    });
});
```

A live demonstration can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/c8Qp8/.

Note, this example needs to be expanded to take care of multiple menus with multiple sub-items. Also, instead of setting your CSS properties with JavaScript you should set them with your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks @jsumners. Your code looks much cleaner. I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

You should set a global variable for the entire  div and use that as a reference

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*Grab the div into a variable*/
    var Pulldown = $('div.pulldown');

    /*Set up your event handlers*/
    $('.options a', Pulldown).click(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        $('.select',Pulldown).html(value);
    });

    /*Toggle the pulldown*/
    Pulldown.toggle(function() {
        Pulldown.css('z-index','110');
        $('.options', Pulldown).css('z-index','100').show('fast');
     }, function(){
         Pulldown.css('z-index','10');
         $('.options', Pulldown).css('z-index','0').hide('fast');
     });
});
```

Live Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RYcr3/2/

Comment: But he definitely should **not** be re-establishing the "click" handler for the anchors in the "toggle" code.